# Node.js jsdom/express response cache?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, svg, jsdom

I'm trying to create a Express server that uses a path parameter to take data to then render in an SVG.

My problem is that when using a REST client to perform GET requests to my route I seem to get a cached response. If I restart my node server I get the response I desire: the '/:data' string is rendered in my SVG. Any subsequent requests just return the first request parameter I submitted after starting up the node server.

If I just return `req.params.data` it is updated every time I make a request as I'd hope; when using it in an SVG render it does not update - my 'rect' element retains the value of the first request.

`app.get('/render/:data' controller.render);`

Controller.js

```
exports.render = function(req, res) {

  var output = renderSVG(req.params.data);

  res.send(output);
  res.end();
};

function renderSVG(data) {
  var svg = window.d3.select('body')
    .append('div').attr('id', 'map')
    .append('svg')
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  svg.append('rect').text(data);

  return window.d3.select('#map').html();
}
```

I'm using D3 and jsdom to render SVG server-side.

I've tried to ensure there is absolutely no caching in my response by using middleware:

```
app.use(function noCache(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  res.setHeader("Expires", 0);
  next();
});
```

Still no avail.

I'm suspecting it has something to do with jsdom...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function renderSVG(data) {
  var svg = window.d3.select('body')
    .append('div').attr('id', 'map')
    .append('svg')
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  svg.append('rect').text(data);

  return window.d3.select('#map').html();
}
```

This looks like you always reuse the same window. When you do `.append('div').attr('id', 'map')`, you always add an additional div to that window, with an id, which will result in your window having multiple divs with the same id. In this case, select by id always returns the first element it finds with that id, leading to you always seeing the same output.